# Can you connect 2 2L gas cans in series?

Tags: fuel

I plan on using 2 2000ml containers, can they be connected in series to the carburetor? Link https://flight-model.com/products/1pc-round-plastic-fuel-tank-250mm-500mm-1000mm-2000mm-for-rc-airplane-model?variant=43486692409571

If so, how would I do this? Would I just connect one of the inlets on the side to the other bottle?

Comment: What kind of aircraft are you putting this on? If you're not going to be primarily in level flight (some kind of stunt drone or whatever) you'll have to consider that the fuel won't necessarily flow naturally from one to the other.